# How to convert string column to udt Vector with float values pyspark

Tags: string, parsing, vector, pyspark

I have a dataframe using pyspark with a column "features" that looks like:

```
[[-0.65467646, 0.578577578, 0.577757775], [-0.65467646, 0.578577578, 0.577757775, 0.65477645, 0.5887563773], [-0.65467646, 0.578577578, 0.577757775]]
```

I would like to apply k-means on it but it gives a type error saying that it's a string and should be converted to Vector.
I did the conversion using udf fonction. It makes something like:

```
Udf_vector=udf(lambda v: Vector(v), UDTVector())
```

but it says now that the values [-0.65467646, 0.578577578, 0.577757775 ... Are not float.
So I did again using udf function:

```
Udf1 =udf(lambda x:[float(y) for y in x])**

df = df.withColumns(col("features", udf(col("features"))
```

But this didn't work. Can someone help me with this I would be very thankful. It's my last step before applying k-means model

[image]

Comment: You can convert the strings into floats before applying function like this : `df = df.withColumn("features", col("features").cast("array<array<float>>"))`

Comment: it gives the following error: pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve '`features`' due to data type mismatch: cannot cast StringType to ArrayType(FloatType,true);

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Comment: What is the type of `features` column? It seems to be array of strings... not array of arrays of strings

Comment: yes it's array of strings; I tried this df4 = df2.withColumn("features", col("features").cast(ArrayType(FloatType())))
It gives "cannot cast string into Arraytype(float)

Comment: @blackbishop you will find an image added in my initial question. I would like to apply k-means on "features" column but it gives the following error: requirement failed: Column features must be of type org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT@3bfc3ba7 but was actually StringType.

Answer (score 0):

Your features column isn't an array type. You'll have first to convert it to an array.

You can remove the square brackets and split the string to get an array.

```
df = df.withColumn("features", split(expr("rtrim(']', ltrim('[', features))"), ","))
```

Now you have an array of strings where each element is an array-like, so you'll need to convert each one to an array too. For Spark 2.4+, you can do this with [`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#transform) function :

```
df = df.withColumn("features", expr("transform(features, x -> split(rtrim(']', ltrim('[', x)), ','))"))
```

Finally, flatten the inner arrays cast the the strings elements to floats and convert to vector:

```
from pyspark.ml.linalg import VectorUDT
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors

array_to_vector = udf(lambda a: Vectors.dense(a), VectorUDT())

df = df.withColumn("features", flatten(col("features")).cast("array<float>"))\
       .withColumn("features", array_to_vector(col("features")))

df.printSchema()

#root
# |-- id: long (nullable = true)
# |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
```

Putting all together:

```
df = df.withColumn("features", split(expr("rtrim(']', ltrim('[', features))"), ",")) \
       .withColumn("features", expr("""transform(features, x -> split(rtrim(']', ltrim('[', x)), ","))"""))\
       .withColumn("features", flatten(col("features")).cast("array<float>"))\
       .withColumn("features", array_to_vector(col("features")))
```

Comment: It gives now TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: I tried another way and converted the column into vector using UDTvector(). It changes the schema to vector type but still gives another error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: [-0.08356357429744941, 0.08524966674774039, -0.0784185383554695, -0.21859354442123433, -0.06993846447509879, -0.01691160239319382, -0.009708906425531714] Maybe it's easier now to find the issue

Comment: It's not clear for... so to resume you have a string column of array-like. You need to convert it to UDTvector. What is the expected type for your function? An array of floats? Because the above code will give you a column of type `array<array<float>>` if you need `array<float>` you can flatten it using : `df.withColumn("features", flatten(col("features")))`. My answer covers just converting the initial string to correct array structure not converting it to vector.

Comment: Actually pyspark is considering that my column is composed of arrays of string values but I need arrays of float numbers in order to apply my algorithm on it. PySpark is considering -0.65765675 as a string and I would like to convert it. I did this now: 'udf1 = f.udf(lambda x : [Vectors.dense(y) for y in x.split(',')], VectorUDT())'
''df3 = df.withColumn('features', udf1(f.col('features')))'' and it gives this error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: [-0.08356357429744941.  I hope I made it clear now